# Conditional formatting with HTMLBody

Tags: html, copy, range, paste

The code below copies a pre-defined range according to a criteria. What does the code in the "Else" line in the "Range function" have to look like so as when the criteria = 0 then only the text in strText2 is taken and pasted in the email Body?. The issue is that I may need two .HTMLBody codes, such as:

for criteria > 1

```
  .HTMLBody = strText & RangetoHTML(rng) & "<br><br>" & GetBoiler(Environ("appdata") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\" & strFilename & ".htm")
```

for criteria = 0

```
  .HTMLBody = strText2
```

GetBoiler Function:

```
Function GetBoiler(ByVal sFile As String) As String
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)

GetBoiler = ts.readall

ts.Close
End Function
```

Range function: 
    Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

```
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempWB As Workbook

With Worksheets("Auswertung")
   loLetzte = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
   .Range("$A$7:$D$" & loLetzte).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">0"
If .AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count > 1 Then
      .AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).Resize(.AutoFilter.Range.Rows.Count - 1). _
    SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Else
 'copy only the strText2  
End If
   .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
End Function
```

Main Sub function:

```
Sub Mail_Klicken()

Dim olApp As Object

Dim datDatum As Date
Dim StrBody As String
Dim intZeile As Integer
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim rng As Range

Dim strMailverteilerTo As String
Dim strText As String
Dim strFilename As String
Dim loLetzte As Long

strMailverteilerTo = "sdfgsdf@gmx.de"


strText = "<span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:""Arial"",""sans-serif"";color:black'>hello,<br><br>hello fellows.<br><br>"


strText2 = "<span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:""Arial"",""sans-serif"";color:black'>dfgfg,<br><br>gfgfgfgfg.<br><br>"

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

With olApp.CreateItem(0)

    .to = strMailverteilerTo
    .Subject = "check"

     strFilename = "Standard"

     If Application.UserName = "asd" Then strFilename = "asd"


    .HTMLBody = strText & RangetoHTML(rng) & "<br><br>" & GetBoiler(Environ("appdata") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\" & strFilename & ".htm")

   .Display

End With
Set olApp = Nothing
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It somehow works. There seems to be no mistake